# Can spells that push enemies around provoke oppurtunity attacks?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, opportunity-attack, forced-movement

Just as the title says, if I cast repelling blast or some other spell that pushes a single enemy away from one of my melee groupies, would that provide an opportunity attack if there was a DM who followed the rules as strict as can be?